# Como faço para que apareça um Modal quando o evento for em uma data já existente no Fullcalendar

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

Tenho um sistema do qual estou usando o Fullcalendar para CRUD. Está funcionando OK, mas fui atentado a um detalhe que havia passado despercebido. Quando o usuário arrastar um determinado evento para outra data no mesmo horário, gostaria que aparecesse um **modal** informando que já existe um evento nesse horário.

A estrutura está dessa forma:

```
......
      $.ajax({
       url:"alterar-dia-agenda.php",
       type:"POST",
       data:{start:start,id:id},

       success:function(sucesso){
            $('#confirmar').modal('show');
            temporiza();
            setTimeout(function() {
               $('.modal').modal('hide');
            }, 2000);
            calendar.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
        }
      });
......
```

**alterar-agenda.php**

```
public function alterarDiaAgenda($id,$titulo,$cor,$data){

  $sqlVerificar = mysqli_query($this->conexao,"SELECT * FROM pe_agenda WHERE DataAgenda = IdAgenda = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($this->conexao,$id)."' AND '".mysqli_real_escape_string($this->conexao,$data)."';");

  if(mysqli_num_rows($sqlVerificar) > 0){
    //return algo;
   }else{
   mysqli_query($this->conexao,"UPDATE pe_agenda SET DataAgenda = '".$data."' WHERE IdAgenda = '".$id."';");
   }
}
```

Quando a alteração ocorre, ele ativa esse modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="confirmar" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header btn-success">
                <h4 class="modal-title text-center"><i class="fas fa-check"></i> Evento Alterado com sucesso!</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Porém gostaria de fazer o mesmo caso haja um evento no mesmo horário, ativar o modal abaixo:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="erro" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header btn-danger">
                <h4 class="modal-title text-center"><i class="fas fa-check"></i> Já existe um evento nesse horário!</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No arquivo `alterar-agenda.php` adicione `echo json_encode(["hasEvent" => mysqli_num_rows($sqlVerificar) > 0]);` e no seu *Ajax* utilize `dataType: 'JSON',` para indicar que você irá receber um objeto e na função `success` você faz a verificação `if (sucesso.hasEvent) { /* Existe */ } else { /* Não Existe */ }`. Ps.: Adicionando o código do `alterar-dia-agenda.php` fica mais fácil de ajuda-lo, mas a lógica é a mesma, retornar `true` quando já existir um evento e caso contrário, retornar `false`.

Comment: Perfeito Valdeir. Funcionou. Muito obrigado!